# opening up a database

Tags: sqlite

I'm a beginner with SQLite and I don't seem to be finding a way to open up a existing database.

I have downloaded sqlite3 to: C:\sqlite3

Inside I have database-file called: hw2tennis.db

I'm trying to open it up using command: .open hw2tennis.db;

And then I am trying to see what's in there using: .schema. I don't know what's wrong, I don't seem to be getting anything out.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). The contents of the console can be copied and pasted directly into your post. Images should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate an issue. Also, did you type `.help` as the error message tells you? What happens when you do?

Comment: Don't put a semicolon after a dot command.

Comment: I tried also without putting the semicolon. I used command: .shell cd. And my working directory is for some reason somewhere in SYSTEM32. I don't understand how to change it to current folder, i guess that's why it's not doing anything.

Comment: EDIT: Now I got the Working Directory somehow to: C:\sqlite3 where it should be and now the commands run and I can open up the databases.

Answer (score 1):

There're some nice and free GUI tools that you can use:

- DB Browser for SQLite at https://sqlitebrowser.org/
- SQLiteStudio at https://sqlitestudio.pl/
- DBeaver at https://dbeaver.io/ (support multiple platforms)
- ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a full pathname to ensure that the file is in the directory that you think it is in. **Use forward-slashes as the directory separator character**. In other words use "c:/work/ex1.db", not "c:\work\ex1.db".

https://sqlite.org/cli.html