# Opening up database and saving the queries

Tags: sqlite

I would need to return a homework.

In the homework i should open up an existing database: hw2tennis.db with sqlite3 and do some basic queries and then return it as .sql file. (I assume that .sql -datafile is the same as .db that I have used to put to the end of every database)

At the moment I know how I can open up a database in sqlite3 and I know how to do basic queries. To my understanding SQLite automatically writes on disk the changes so I don't need to save or anything when I do changes to tables and so on.

But I was wondering, is there a way to save the file in a way, that when someone opens it up, **they will see the Queries I have made to it.**

For example, if task 1 is:

1. Print all players and their information

So basically, I would write to SQlite: SELECT * FROM Player;

But, when I open up the hw2tennis.db again, there is only the tables and not the queries which is of course logical.

**So can I save the FILE in a way that the teacher can see the queries made?**

Thanks!

Comment: The SQLite command line app has no direct way to save the queries you enter.  Ask your teacher what they expect, likely they expect a text file that you can run with the command line app, but that's a guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a reply! Do you happen to know about the .save command? Now I am just quitting the SQLite3 and it saves everything automatically. What's the purpose of the .save? (At first, I thought that the .save could be used to save the Queries)

Comment: The `.help` for it says "Write database to FILE (an alias for .backup ...)".  In other words, it creates a backup copy of the database.  Most SQLite commands run on the command line run in a transaction that's designed to be written to disk when control is returned to the user, unless you manually create a transaction and don't close it.

Answer (score 0):

Just answered to your another question at [opening up a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74749422/opening-up-a-database)

You can save your queries and outputs in a directory of your Windows system (per your screenshot) and send them with the SQLite DB file to your teachers

There're some nice and free GUI tools that you can use:

- DB Browser for SQLite at https://sqlitebrowser.org/
- SQLiteStudio at https://sqlitestudio.pl/
- DBeaver at https://dbeaver.io/ (support multiple platforms)
- ...etc.